# How to replace the last character of a string matched by Regex expression (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create an array from a string containing addresses and need to replace the comma separators with semicolons since addresses contain many commas and `arr.split` will create incorrect entries.

I can't figure out how to match the commas that only appear after zip codes.

After some research I've been trying to use: `str.replace(/(?<=\d{5}),/g, "; ");`

the `(?<=y)x` expression doesn't seem to be working, but every other method I think of ends up deleting both the zip and the comma or just plain doesn't do anything. ([source where I found all I know of Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)).

Comment: Maybe `str.replace(/(\d{5}),/g, "$1;")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way will work **if** the JavaScript engine supports lookbehind, which was only added in ES2018:

```js
// ONLY WORKS ON ENGINES THAT SUPPORT LOOKBEHIND
const str = "Testing 90210,testing,testing, ...";
console.log(str.replace(/(?<=\d{5}),/g, "; "));
```

Otherwise, match the zip code as well in a capture group and use `$1` to include it in the replacement:

```js
const str = "Testing 90210,testing,testing, ...";
console.log(str.replace(/(\d{5}),/g, "$1; "));
```